# change order of attributes on product page (per product)

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, product-page

I would like to change the order of attributes on our product page. I know I can change this order that will apply to all product pages that these attributes exist, but I was wondering if I can change that order on a per product level.

EG. https://www.herbcottage.com.au/dried-burdock-root.html
Actions: I want these to appear in order of their importance to each herb.

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is no option to sort product attributes for each product page, But you can create a custom table which stores

1. Product Id.
2. Product Attribute-Id Id.
3. Position.

After this, all you need is to join with this table and get the list of all attributes and its position and display it in the view.phtml table.

Hope this is useful.